# How to run a program on boot up?

Tags: linux, boot, init-script

So I have this program which I manually run as root :

```
sudo gammu-smsd -c /etc/gammu-smsdrc -d
```

What this does is it runs the Gammu (software to manage gsm modems) and 'daemonize' it. My problem is I want this program to automatically run on boot up .

Is it ok to just edit root's crontab and stick this command there? Or there's some other way?

(Im using Ubuntu 11.04.)

Comment: You probably don't need the sudo when you put it in the startup files since most stuff there is executed by root.

Comment: You might first ask yourself if you want that to be run *before* or *after* a user logs in.

Comment: It maybe worth looking at creating init.d scripts for your daemon, However your requirement so up to you.

Comment: I would like to run before a user logs in. The thing is I want my server to run my programs (not just gammu) even if im not around during a power failure in which the computer reboots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about **/etc/rc.local**?

This will be executed last in the startup sequence.

Comment: add `sleep 1m` before `gammu-smsd -d`. I know this is not recommended, but this is the easy way to make it working. You might  need also look for creating init.d script

Answer (score 3):

You can use **crontab** for this.
Use `crontab -e` to edit user's crontab (A list of start-up scripts that users have added).
Add following line at the end:

```
@reboot <command>
```

Examples:

- `@reboot my_script.sh`
- `@reboot python my_script.py arg1 arg2`

Finally use `contab -l` to make sure your script was added to the list.

Comment: `Command 'contab' not found`.

Comment: Use `apt-get install cron`

Answer (score 0):

May this help you ?

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-add-a-program-to-the-ubuntu-startup-list-after-login/

---

Or just add it in the `/etc/profile`

or do add it the recommended way : http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/

Indeed, remove the sudo !
(but you will need it to do the edit or to add the command, so...)

Comment: it executes the program after the login, i was hoping something that gets executed before that, or during the login window is shown ,or without needing to login

Comment: see my edit : add it in the system-wide startup file

Comment: Louis: do I need to remove `sudo` if i follow that guide?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/) is how on how to add a startup script to be run at bootup. You can find more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto).

Comment: The link you gave is very outdated. From what I know, the booting procedure has much changed since.